# EF won't update tables based on my model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, datacontext, seeding

At first I created a Person model which only contained the basic properties:

```
[Table("SGDB_Persons")]
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Department Department { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public SourceType SourceType { get; set; }
```

After I noticed I'm missing something I've added a new PersonData Property:

```
[Required]
    public PersonData PersonData { get; set; }
```

Unfortunately EF won't update the Database at all - PersonData which at first contained an object of type Person got updated so there is no Person property anymore. On the other hand, EF does not create a new Column for PersonData_Id.

[image]

Additionally the ID column is not auto-incrementing (all other table's Id Column do). What's confusing me is the following Constraing which gets created inside my Person table:

> CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.SGDB_Persons_dbo.SGDB_PersonData_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[SGDB_PersonData] ([Id])

I tried everything (at least I think so). I dropped all tables / the whole database manually, reinstalled EF, executed manual migrations but nothing seems to work.

I think it's this problem which causes me to not be able to seed my database with the following code:

```
protected override void Seed(PersonContext context) {
        base.Seed(context);
        var dep = new DepartmentContext().Departments.First();

        var status = new Status("Test");
        var persondata = new PersonData(status);
        context.Status.Add(status);
        context.PersonData.Add(persondata);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var person = new Person {
                Firstname = $"TestPersonFirstname{i}",
                Lastname = $"TestPersonLastname{i}",
                SourceType = COM.SourceType.Manual,
                Department = dep,
                PersonData = persondata
            };
            context.Persons.Add(person);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Everytime this code get's executed I'm getting an Exception:

> The member with identity 'SGDB.DAL.Contexts.Person_Department' does not exist in the metadata collection. Parameter name: identity.

I don't know if both problems are related to the same problem but both need to be resolved :)

Thanks in advance!

**Update 1**

My Solution is divided into a few different Projects:

BLL, DAL, COM, UI

DataContexts are located inside the DAL project, Models inside the COM project.

Department Model:

```
[Table("SGDB_Departments")]
public class Department {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Costcenter { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string FullDepartmentName {
        get {
            return $@"{Division.Abbreviation}\{Abbreviation}";
        }
    }
    [Required]
    public virtual Division Division { get; set; }
}
```

PersonData Model:

```
[Table("SGDB_PersonData")]
public class PersonData {
    public PersonData(Status status) {
        Status = status;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Limit { get; set; }
    public Person Responsible { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

The Person table (as you can see) has got a Department_Id column (EF inserted automatically).

**Clarification**

A Person object contains a PersonData object as additional Information for this Person. A Person may / may not has a Responsible Person (so PersonData.Responsible is not a Navigation Property to the Parent Person).
Additionaly if possible I don't want to have a foreign Key inside the PersonData table.

As I figured out I'd have to modify

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
       .HasRequired(e => e.PersonData)
       .WithRequiredPrincipal(e => e.Responsible)
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

to

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
       .HasRequired(e => e.PersonData)
       .WithMany()
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

I'll try this and report in if it solved my problem.

**Update 2**

> The member with identity 'SGDB.DAL.Contexts.Person_Department' does not exist in the metadata collection.

Comment: Is PersonData in the same project? What does your context look like?

Comment: Please include `Department` and `PersonData` models. Sounds like relationship configuration problem.

Comment: @SteveGreene - see my question for updated information.

Comment: @IvanStoev I think so, too. I created all models the same way - after executing the project the first time EF created everything on it's own - even the foreign keys were created by EF (I don't want to insert additional ID-Properties if it's not neccessary). Then I removed the Person Property from PersonData and included a PersonData Property inside the Person class - after that EF never ever changed anything in the DB - even if I create a new string property inside the Model nothing happens in the database.

Comment: I think the problem is `Person.PersonData` (required), `PersonData.Responsible` (optional). In such setup EF infers `one-to-one` relationship `Person->PersonData` with `PersonData` being **principal** and `Person` being **dependent**. in other words, `PersonData` owns `Person`. That's why the auto increment column is in `PersonData` table, and `Person.Id` is simple `int` both PK and FK.

Comment: @IvanStoev That sounds like you're right - but how could I solve that? At first PersonData owned a Person object until I realized that this makes no sense - then I modified those classes so that Person owns a PersonData object.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have 1 person -> 1 data, and both are required, i.e. you create/delete a person along with data?

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, one Person contains one PersonData and if a Person gets deleted their Data shall be deleted, too. What I don't understand is - how would the reason you described affect the model so that if I add a Property (e.g. public string FullName {get; set;} ) EF won't add a new column inside the Person table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model defines `one-to-one` relationship between `Person` and `PersonData` with later being required and the former - optional. EF always uses the required side of the `one-to-one` relationship as **principal** and optional part as **dependent**. Hence it thinks `PersonaData` is the principal and `Person` - dependent and reflects that in database table design.

You need the opposite and also both sides being **required**. When both sides are required or optional, EF cannot automatically derive the principal/dependent side and there is no way to specify that via data annotations (attributes), so you need a fluent API setup.

Override your DbContext `OnModelCreating` and add something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()               
        .HasRequired(e => e.PersonData)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal(e => e.Responsible)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

What it does is to tell EF that both sides of the `Person->PersonData` relationship are required and `Person` is the principal. This should make again your `Person.Id` column auto-increment and should resolve the person-data part of the problem.

The other thing I've noticed is this line:

```
var dep = new DepartmentContext().Departments.First();
```

while all other parts of the same procedure are using a variable called `context`. This might/might not be a problem, just check it out.

**UPDATE:** From the clarification in the updated question it turns out you have **two** relationships between `Person` and `PersonData`, so you need separate configuration for each of them like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.PersonData)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<PersonData>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.Responsible)
    .WithOptionalDependent() // or WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Please note that there is no way to not introduce additional FK column in the `PersonData` table. It's needed to represent the `Responsible` relation, so you'll end up with a table column called `Responsible_Id`.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow. For the last part: Because Department and Person got different contexts, when seeding I need to get a Department from the database and insert it into my new person object - is this the right attempt or should it be done in a different way? Regarding the first part, I forgot to mention that even the PersonData table hasn't got a column for a Person_ID (I'll recheck this as soon as I'm able to view my database)

Comment: It will not - see [Shared Primary Key Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations)

Comment: Ok, i read your your post once again and I think I have to clarify that Person Responsible is *not* the original Person object. A Person contains PersonData - PersonData.Responsible could be null if the Person does not have a responsible person (because of this Responsible is not required).

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot to mention you in my previous comment. Am I right that the overridden OnModelCreate Method assumes that PersonData.Responsible is a foreign key for the actual Person? Because A Person has 0..1 PersonData.Responsible.

Comment: Correct. This is what EF assumes (w/o fluent config) when see `Person Resonsible` - the name of the property doesn't matter, it looks only at types. So yes, the answer is not correct, I've tried to clarify the case before posting it. Anyway, so you have 2 relationships between the person and data, I'm not sure data.Responsible can be made 1 -> 0..1 In all the cases it will help if you define both sides of the relationships (bidirectional navigation properties).

Comment: I'm not really deep into EF so please don't kill me for asking "special" qiestions :) - I've added a final clarification - now I'll try to force the OnModelCreate event to be fired (so that the database gets updated?) and report in.

Comment: Deal :) There is no need to do something special, once you override, it will be called by EF when needed.

Comment: Just one more question :) Can 1 person be responsible for many (other person's) data?

Comment: I've updated the question once again (hopefully the last time :) ) - The error mentioned in Update 2 gets thrown in the Seeding-Method of Persons (exactly when adding the Person to the Context). You may know what went wrong here? To answer your question: A Responsible is not really responsible for data but for the Person itself - so PersonData.Responsible is a responsible Person for the Person object. Ps. The db got updated as I imagined - the person table now has got a PersonData_Id column :)

Comment: Now I'm pretty sure the error is because of the different context.

Comment: Obviously.. but how could I retrieve an object of Type department to reference to when Seeding Persons?

Comment: If it's the same database, then simply use the `context` variable. If not, then you need to first seed (transfer) the departments. But that is another story which can't be covered here. You seem to have 2 issues - model design and seed. I think we covered the first, I would suggest you to post another question (could be linked to this) specific to seed issue.